# MYSQL - BASIC QUERYS where + group by + having

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT dieet.snr, soort.nsnaam   FROM soort
JOIN dieet ON soort.snr = dieet.snr
JOIN voedsel ON dieet.voednr = voedsel.voednr 
WHERE voedsel.voednr = 22 
GROUP BY dieet.snr
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ;
```

**the where condition messes up my output, what am i doing wrong**

Comment: What do you mean by "*messes up my output*"?  What is your underlying data?  What output were you expecting?  What do you get instead?

Comment: i expect less data but i am getting more, almost like the group by is ignored and count to

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit.  Please show some examples by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13809764/edit) and/or posting on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking for "snr"s that have exactly one record that is a "voednr = 22".  Your query is getting all "snr"s that have exactly one such "voednr", along with other "voednr"s.

Let me suggest the following query:

```
SELECT dieet.snr, soort.nsnaam
FROM soort
JOIN dieet ON soort.snr = dieet.snr
JOIN voedsel ON dieet.voednr = voedsel.voednr 
GROUP BY dieet.snr
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 and max(voedsel.voednr) = 22
```

This will get you the rows with the one and only 22.

Comment: thanks mate!!! this is what i whas looking for, how you managed to figure that out with such a vague description i do not know! but iappreciate it

Comment: @user1880803 . . . I have a certain amount of experience trying to figure out what people really mean ;)

Comment: but why cant i do this:HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 and WHERE voedsel.voednr = 22

Comment: but why cant i do this:HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 and WHERE voedsel.voednr = 22